# integration of radial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to integrate the following equation:

$\frac{dr}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{m} (E-V)- \frac{\ell^2}{m^2r^2}} = \frac{dr}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{dr}{d\theta} \frac{\ell}{mr^2}$

where E,m,$\ell$ are all constant and $r, \theta$ are the variables. The goal is to find a function $\theta (r)$.

I've noticed that the first member of the equation is multiplied by $d\theta/d\theta$ and then in the 3rd member instead of doing the derivative of r with respect to t, it is done with respect to $\theta$. Is it always possible to multiply differentials by other differentials as they cancel out, rather than doing derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2_0}-\frac{1}{r^2}},~r_0=\frac{l}{2m(E-V)}$$
$$\implies\int \frac{r_0 dr}{r\sqrt{r^2-r^2_0}}=\int d\theta$$
Let $r=r_0~ sec ~ u$, 
$$\implies \int du= \int d\theta \implies \sec^{-1} (r/r_0)=\theta+C$$
$$\implies r=r_0 ~sec(\theta+C)$$